# Can't get cordova.file plugin to work in a hybrid app

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I'm having a problem reading a file from the file system using `cordova.file` plugin. I'm using the following sample code:

```
    function onInitFs(fileSystem) {
        console.log("filesystem loaded!");
        fileSystem.root.getFile(filePath, {}, function (fileEntry) {
            console.log("DirectoryEntry.getFile succeeded!");
            fileEntry.file(function (file) {
                console.log("FileEntry.file succeeded!");
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onloadend = function (e) {
                    //file contents are in this.result
                };

                reader.readAsText(file);
            }, console.log);
        }, console.log);
    }

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onInitFs, console.log);
```

And here is the error message I'm seeing in the output window:

```
D/PluginManager( 2597): init()
E/cutils  (  915): Failed to mkdirat(/storage/sdcard/Android): Read-only file system
W/ContextImpl( 2597): Failed to ensure directory: /storage/sdcard/Android/data/io.cordova.<myappname>/files
W/System.err( 2597): java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err( 2597):    at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.getAvailableFileSystems(FileUtils.java:132)
W/System.err( 2597):    at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.initialize(FileUtils.java:192)
W/System.err( 2597):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginEntry.createPlugin(PluginEntry.java:96)
W/System.err( 2597):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.startupPlugins(PluginManager.java:195)
W/System.err( 2597):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.init(PluginManager.java:106)
W/System.err( 2597):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.loadUrlIntoView(CordovaWebView.java:457)
W/System.err( 2597):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.loadUrlIntoView(CordovaWebView.java:444)
W/System.err( 2597):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.loadUrlIntoView(CordovaWebView.java:541)
W/System.err( 2597):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.loadUrl(CordovaWebView.java:435)
W/System.err( 2597):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.loadUrl(CordovaActivity.java:391)
W/System.err( 2597):    at io.cordova.<myappname>.onCreate(ApprovalsHybrid.java:33)
W/System.err( 2597):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
W/System.err( 2597):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
W/System.err( 2597):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
W/System.err( 2597):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
W/System.err( 2597):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
W/System.err( 2597):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
W/System.err( 2597):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err( 2597):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err( 2597):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
W/System.err( 2597):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 2597):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err( 2597):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
W/System.err( 2597):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
W/System.err( 2597):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/System.out( 2597): Error adding plugin org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.
W/Vold    (  915): Returning OperationFailed - no handler for errno 30
```

I'm using Multi-Device Hybrid Apps plug-in for VS and Android Emulator.

**UPDATE1:** my **`config.xml`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps" id="io.cordova.<myappname>" version="1.0.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
  <name><myappname></name>
  <description>
    A blank project that uses Apache Cordova to help you build an app that targets multiple mobile platforms: Android, iOS, Windows, and Windows Phone.
  </description>
  <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">
    Apache Cordova Team
  </author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <vs:features>
    <vs:feature>org.apache.cordova.globalization@0.2.8</vs:feature>
    <vs:feature>org.apache.cordova.file@1.2.0</vs:feature>
  </vs:features>
  <vs:platformSpecificValues />
</widget>
```

**UPDATE2:** alright, I figured out that there are some problems with `cordova.file` plugin v1.2.0. When I switch `cordova.file` plugin version from v1.2.0 to v1.1.0, I get to the point where success callback of the `requestFileSystem` gets called. But `getFile` fails with `FileNotFoundException`. The reason for that may be incorrect relative path.

**UPDATE3:** fixed incorrect usage of `readAsText`

Comment: Whats in your Config?

Comment: I've added config.xml contents to the question

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a `fileEntry` object to `readAsText` instead of a `file` object, which will not work. You should do this instead.

1. Create a file object by calling `fileEntry.file`
2. Pass the `file` object to a function that then calls `readAsText` with the file object passed in. This will read in the file correctly.

Here's the Cordova [file API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html) for your reference. You can see how it is done in the FileReader example.

When the read succeeds, the output window will show an `I/chromium` message with the contents of the file it just read.

Comment: That's a good point, I will fix it, but the success callback of the `getFile` call is not even getting called yet.